# Arithmetic Mean of Partial Sums of Geometric Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have the simple geometric series $\Sigma\,x_n$ where $x_n = (-1)^n$ so that $\Sigma\,x_n$ diverges. However, I know that the sequence $(\sigma_n)_n = \frac{1}{n}\Sigma\,s_n$ converges, where $s_n$ are the partial sums $x_1+x_2+...+x_n$, and that $lim\,\sigma_n$ exists.

I can almost prove this and find the limit as follows:

$s_n = \Sigma\,x_n = -1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1\,\,+\,\,...\,+\,(-1)^n$

And so

$\sigma_n = \frac{1}{n}(-1+0-1+0-1\,\,+\,\,...\,+\,\Sigma\,x_n)$

Which results in a series of the form:

$(\sigma_n)_n= (-1, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{3}{5}, -\frac{1}{2}, \,\,...)$

Such that I can infer the following pattern (apologies for my present inability to properly represent piecewise functions):

$\sigma_n= \{^{-\frac{1}{2},\,\,n\,even}_{-(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}),\,\,n\,odd} $

From here, it's obvious that the sequence has a total of two subsequential limits that are both equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$, so $lim\,\sigma_n=-\frac{1}{2}$.

However, I can't figure out a satisfying way to properly prove the sequence is equal to what I've inferred. Is there something I can do beyond just calculating enough terms to make a good guess? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s_n
=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k$
so
$s_{2n}
=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k
=\sum_{k=1}^{n} ((-1)^{2k-1}+(-1)^{2k}
=0
$
and
$s_{2n+1}
=s_{2n}+(-1)^{2n+1}
=-1
$.

Therefore,
if
$\sigma_n
=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n s_k
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\sigma_{2n}
&=\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} s_k\\
&=\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (s_{2k-1}+s_{2k})\\
&=\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1+0)\\
&=-\frac12\\
\end{array}$

We also have

$\begin{array}\\
\sigma_{2n+1}
&=\frac1{2n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} s_k\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}(\sum_{k=1}^{2n} s_k+s_{2n+1})\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}(2n\sigma_{2n}+s_{2n+1})\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}(-2n\frac12-1)\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}(-n-1)\\
&=-\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\\
&=-\frac{n+1/2+1/2}{2n+1}\\
&=-\frac12-\frac{1}{4n+2}\\
\end{array}
$

This is more than enough to prove that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma_n
=-\frac12
$.

Comment: Great! It was the bit at the top, defining the odd and even terms of $s_n$ analytically, that I hadn't done and was leaving me unsatisfied. I guess I just needed to get my hands dirty and calculate. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Whenever I see a sum involving $(-1)^n$, my immediate attack is to pair the even and odd terms (or, when the sum starts at 1, the odd and even terms). That usually works.